# Is it sufficient to learn YUI for the development with Alloy UI?

Tags: javascript, yui, liferay, javascript-framework, alloy-ui

There is not really much information available for Alloy UI (the current JavaScript framework for Liferay 6.x), and as it builds on top of YUI, is it enough to get a book for YUI and scan through their documentation?

Somehow I'm not able to find any books or resources (plugins, except the one from the Liferay page), or is it just too new?

Comment: AlloyUI is actually YUI. Alloy clearly appeared as a necessity because YUI3 started with a small core with lots of Beta features. Currently as of YUI 3.4.0 there are many components already included in YUI, so as times goes on Alloy is becoming less necessary. Whatever YUI components you chose to use (from Alloy, from the Core or from the Gallery), learn to use YUI. You won't regret it.

Comment: Thanks, the necessity for the question arises when you have to work with Liferay and thus consider using Alloy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Alloy UI is quite new, but you should be fine when learning the YUI library. As you will see, they are quite equal

Comment: hmm ..I guess so, since AUI builds atop of YUI (for api: http://yuilibrary.com/ and http://alloy.liferay.com/deploy/api/ ..has to do for now.. thx)